# Convert Specfic chat keyword to link?

Tags: php

Okay i am writing a basic chat application that stores messages into database.

```
public function get_Messages() {

    $rows = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT user,message,TS FROM chat ORDER BY TS DESC LIMIT 50 ) sub ORDER BY TS ASC");

    foreach ($rows->results() as $row) {

        $text = $row->message;
        $keywords = array('AAPL', 'BBL');

        $regex = '/('.implode('|', $keywords).')/i';

        $output = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="apage">\\1</a>', $text);

        echo $row->TS . '<br/><strong>' .$row->user . '</strong> says: <br/>';
        echo $output . '<br/><br/>';
    }

}
```

The Above Code changed AAPL into a link BUT only when AAPL is the only word in the message. How about if i have something like this as the message:

Hello check this link out AAPL

I still want to be able to output the entire message with the link included?

Comment: Look for preg_match functionnality

Comment: you might look for `preg_match` and `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<?Php
$str="Visit the homepage and menu  of my site ";
echo preg_replace("/(homepage|menu)/i","<a href='http://example.com/$1'>$1</a>",$str);


?>
```

$1 is a backrefrance that contains the matched  word matched in the capture group

eg : hompage or menu or other.

Comment: How do you make it so the link opens as a new windows. Right now the link appends to current page url.